# Instead of repeating each function like so in php, would it be more efficient to use a for each loop?

Tags: php

It's very redundant and I only want to say "OK TO SEND" one time for whatever part is being requested and whatever variation of multiple parts that are being selected.

```
if ($this->part1) return "OK TO SEND: $this->part1 ";
if ($this->part2) return "OK TO SEND: $this->part2 ";
if ($this->part3) return "OK TO SEND: $this->part3 ";
if ($this->part4) return "OK TO SEND: $this->part4 ";
if ($this->part5) return "OK TO SEND: $this->part5 ";
if ($this->part6) return "OK TO SEND: $this->part6 ";
if ($this->part7) return "OK TO SEND: $this->part7 ";
```

I'm not sure if i just use if and ifelse statements or a loop. I'm certain a loop would be most efficient. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Something like this?

```
$params = array($this->part1, $this->part2, $this->part3, $this->part4, $this->part5, $this->part6, $this->part7) ;
```

would i than use an in_array function?

Comment: Is there any reason for them not to be in an array?

Comment: Most importantly, it would be more maintainable.

Comment: An array might be perfect, i'll post what i have.

Comment: In response to what you just posted, MiniGod is wondering why are your parts stored as separate variables as opposed to being stored as `$this->parts[0]`,`$this->parts[1]`.. etc.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but i'm not opposed to working it in an array like that.

Comment: @JeremyBanks retracting.

Comment: It would also help a bit to show what your "Interface" is.  What is the header for the function that uses this redundant code..?  I'm mostly just asking because the way you asked isn't detailed enough to answer very specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$params = array($this->part1, $this->part2, $this->part3, $this->part4, $this->part5, $this->part6, $this->part7);

// This will return a string noting the only option selected
function partRequested($params) {
  foreach($params as $part) {
    if($part) // or maybe ($part !== false) depending on what is contained
      return 'OK TO SEND: ' . $part . ' ';
  }
}

// This will return a single string noting all the options selected
function partsRequested($params) {
  foreach($params as $part) {
    if($part) // or maybe ($part !== false) depending on what is contained
      $result .= 'OK TO SEND: ' . $part . ' <br />';
  }
  return $result;
}
```

The returned string from partsRequested() will look like:

```
OK TO SEND: part1
OK TO SEND: part3
OK TO SEND: part4
OK TO SEND: part5
// etc
```

Here it is with a little bit different formatting

```
// This will return a single string noting all the options selected, different formatting
function partsRequested($params) {
  foreach($params as $part) {
    if($part) // or maybe ($part !== false) depending on what is contained
      $result .= $part . ' <br />';
  }
  return $result;
}

// Then to echo the results
if($result = partsRequested($params))
  echo 'OK TO SEND: ' . $result;
```

The string echoed will look like this:

```
OK TO SEND: part1
part3
part4
part5
```

Comment: Then you need to change your question to reflect that. This is what is says above:  "I only want to say "OK TO SEND" one time for whatever part is being requested"

Comment: This is fairly clear i like it but i would need it to list out all parts selected, multiple select boxes. Thanks and sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @HeadWay What is being done with these returned strings? Are they simply being output somewhere?

Comment: @HeadWay Ok, soo rather than building an array of strings to return and then having to iterate over them, you could just build a single string from the function and return that. This will let you simply echo the results. I'll change the code above.

Comment: still not working, it's returning as array() and not the actual product names.

Comment: That second function works but now it's repeating OK TO SEND with every product selected. Thank you so much for being patient. Almost there.

Comment: @HeadWay also, what will be contained in $this->part1? I'm assuming this will either be a string or an empty string.

Comment: a string with the product name of what they have selected in the drop down box.

Comment: @HeadWay I made another edit. This one returns a string a just the selected parts. You will have to add the 'OK TO SEND: ' prefix wherever you are outputting the string. I hopes this gets it working for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
for($c = 1; $c < 8; $c++)
{
   $part = "part" . $c;
   if($this->$part)
      return "OK TO SEND: " . $this->$part . " ";
}
```

I would recommend this over your approach since you may need to add more parts later.

EDIT: if you wanted an array of the active items you could do something like this:

```
$active = array();
for($c = 1; $c < 8; $c++)
{
   $part = "part" . $c;
   if($this->$part)
      $active[] = $part;
}
return $active;
```

-Ken

Comment: This looks pretty ugly. An array would be a cleaner way to do what he wants, as noted by other comments. Edit : but you're definitely right about the maintainability thing.

Comment: Manu, in hindsight i totally agree...thats what i get for answering on the fly...

Comment: Will this be able to list out all the parts if say... 4 or 5 parts are all selected at once?

Comment: not as it stands, but neither would the code you posted above. see my edis above if you wanted to get say an array of active items

Comment: Right now it's returning array()

Comment: right, you'd have to play with that array to get the output to look exactly how you want, the array would have elements like this (say part1 and part5 were true): [part1,part5]